# Custom jQuery/JavaScript Slider bugging out when I click on arrows/navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm working on creating my own responsive JavaScript/jQuery slider. It seems to be working pretty awesome for the most part, however, when I click on the arrows or navigation circles the timeout / animations seem to bug out. It is not consistent. When the arrows/nav circles are clicked, it should just reset the timeout and go to the corresponding slide.

For example if you click on a nav circle when it gets to the last slide it quickly goes right back to the first slide without the 5000 pause.

Here is the fiddle with all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/23712cwb/2/

Why is the timing bugging out like that? How do I fix it? As you can see I added `clearTimeout($timeout);` to the top of the `nextSlide()` function, but that didn't totally resolve it and I'm unsure this is the correct approach to the problem. However, before I added this line of code it was even more buggy.

Also if anyone has any tips they can give me or suggestions on how to make this even better that would be awesome. I am not very familiar with jQuery plugins so I am just kind of winging it here.

Comment: FYI: Seems fine in chrome on my MAC

Comment: @AlexThomas try clicking on the navigation circles a couple of times, then wait for the next few slides to automatically be animated. You'll see the timers are not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. This code was causing the issue:

```
    $('.slider .slides li .caption, .slider .slide-arrows li, .slider .slide-nav').mouseout(function () {
        $timeout = setTimeout(function () { nextSlide('right', $slides, $height, $caption_speed, $slide_speed, 'null'); }, $slide_speed);
    });
```

So every time I took my mouse off of the arrows or nav or caption it was doubling up on executing the nextSlide function.

I removed that code and it's all gravy now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code doesn't work on Firefox, because he is less forgiving than Chrome about errors.

You should define the functions captionActive and nextSlide you use outside of $(document).ready block

With your example it gave me this error on the console :

```
 captionActive is not defined
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23712cwb/3/)

Edit : I guess you should be careful with the scope of $timeout : as you use it in the block document.ready and in functions, you should make use of global variables and work with window.$timeout instead of $timeout

That might solve some of your problems.

Comment: Yeah firefox was trying to initiate the function before it was declared...thanks for that. It is still bugged out though when you click nav circles or arrows.

Comment: I edited my answer : try to use global variables explicitly with window object!